# FFC on the back of a Chromebook Pixel Display Assembly

Tags: protocol, driver

[image: The FFC in question]
Hello!
I want to get the touch overlay of a Chromebook Pixel Display Assembly to work. I attached a picture of the Cable coming out of a mxT1664S touch controller. Can someone tell me what type of receptacle I need to make a breakout board? Also, any clues about what this cable might transfer are highly appreciated.
Thank you!